# Existence of a number using Borel-Cantelli

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n<\infty$. Show that there exists a number $x\in[0,1]$ such that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}<\infty$$

My attempt was to let $X\sim U[0,1]$ be a random variable and define events which will allow me to use Borel-Cantelli lemma. However, those are only ideas and I wasn't able to make a lot of progress.

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you give a little more detail about your Borel Cantelli strategy? I am thinking along the lines of assuming no such $x$ exists and formulating a way to use Borel Cantelli II

Comment: I tried many things such as $A_N=\{\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}<\epsilon\}$. Nothing led me to something interesting enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_n:= (a_n-b_n,a_n+b_n)\cap [0,1]$. By assumption, $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\lambda(A_n)<\infty$ hence by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, almost every $x$ belongs to at most finitely many $A_n$. Moreover, if $x\notin A_n$, then
$$
\frac{b_n^2}{|x-a_n|}\leqslant b_n.$$

Comment: Davide's answer is the heart of the question, but I would like to add the details. Denote $A:= \{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\cup \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} A_n$. Since Borel Cantelli says $\lambda(A) = 0$, we know that $\lambda([0,1]\setminus A)=1$. So a.e. $x$ belongs to at most finitely many $A_n$ and those $x$ are not $a_n$ themselves to avoid a technicality. The final inequality follows from the fact that for such $x\in A_n^c$ we have $b_n\leq |x-a_n|$. Thus, for $x\in A^c$ you have finitely many terms which can be quite large and the rest are bounded by the $b_n$ term.

Comment: Such an elegant solution. Thanks a lot!